# Ventajas y desventajas de expresiones Lambda en java 8, ¿Cuales son sus utilidades?

Tags: java

Java 1.8 ha traído con sigo cambios importantes en nuestra manera de programar y en concreto uno de ellos son las llamadas expresiones lambdas. Estas expresiones acortan en gran medida el código de nuestro aplicativo pero que implicaciones tiene esto realmente en el rendimiento del mismo.

- ¿De que manera nos benefician o perjudican este tipos de expresiones
  y como afecta al rendimiento del aplicativo?
- ¿La optimización de estas expresiones puede mejorar el rendimiento
  del código tradicional y ayuda a reducir código realmente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Efectivamente, las expresiones Lambda, junto con la API Stream son los dos cambios más significativos introducidos en Java 8, tal como se explica en [este documento introductorio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/expresiones-lambda-api-stream-java-2633852-esa.html).

### ¿Cuáles son sus beneficios?

He aquí algunos:

- podemos crear código más claro y conciso, ya que las expresiones lambda nos permiten referenciar métodos anónimos o métodos sin nombre, sin tener que recurrir al uso de clases anónimas. Cuando se escribe una expresión Lambda, se traduce en una interfaz funcional en tiempo de compilación. Aquí hay un ejemplo del uso de expresiones Lambda para reemplazar una clase interna anónima con un código mucho más limpio y legible.

#### Sin Lambda:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println(“Action Detected”);
    }

});
```

#### Con Lambda:

```
button.addActionListener(e -> {
    System.out.println(“Action Detected”);
});
```

- se abre la puerta hacia la programación funcional en Java, en donde las funciones juegan un papel fundamental. Esto significa poder pasar funciones, en tiempo de ejecución, como valores de variables, valores de retorno o parámetros de otras funciones. Este es un concepto muy poderoso que se puede entender como la posibilidad de pasar comportamiento como valor y es precisamente lo que podemos lograr con la adición de expresiones lambda al lenguaje Java.
- al usarlas en combinación con la API Stream podremos realizar operaciones de tipo filtro/mapeo/reducción sobre colecciones de datos de forma secuencial o paralela y que su implementación sea transparente para el desarrollador.
- cuando la expresión lambda se compone de una sola sentencia e invoca algún método existente por medio de su nombre, existe la posibilidad de escribirla usando métodos de referencia, con lo cual se logra un código más compacto y fácil de leer.
- se reduce en efecto la escritura de código. (Ver al respecto el caso de ejemplo planteado en el artículo *Introducción a Expresiones Lambda*

### ¿Tiene desventajas?

Pues sí, tiene una (aunque más que *desventaja* podemos llamarle un reto, el reto de superarnos, de seguir aprendiendo).

Para aprender a usar las expresiones Lambda (así como la API Stream), se requiere un cambio de paradigma en la forma en la que hemos escrito código Java hasta el momento.

Pero la superación de esa barrera tiene su recompensa, ya que tendremos en nuestras manos una herramienta poderosísima que nos va a facilitar la vida.

### Algunos ejemplos para ver las diferencias

#### 1. Implementación de `Runnable`

```
//Sin Lambda:
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Sin Lambda");
    }
}).start();

//Con Lambda:
new Thread( () -> System.out.println("Con Lambda") ).start();
```

#### 2. Manejo de eventos

```
// Sin Lambda:
JButton show =  new JButton("Show");
show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.out.println("Sin Lambda");
        }
     });


// Con Lambda:
show.addActionListener((e) -> {
    System.out.println("Con Lambda");
});
```

#### 3. Iterando sobre listas

```
//Sin Lambda :
List features = Arrays.asList("Lambdas", "Default Method", "Stream API", "Date and Time API");
for (String feature : features) {
   System.out.println(feature);
}

//Con Lambda:
List features = Arrays.asList("Lambdas", "Default Method", "Stream API", "Date and Time API");
features.forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
```

#### 4. Ejemplo de Map y Reduce

En el código se aplicará el 12% en cada compra

```
// Sin Lambda:
List costBeforeTax = Arrays.asList(100, 200, 300, 400, 500);
for (Integer cost : costBeforeTax) {
      double price = cost + .12*cost;
      System.out.println(price);
}

// Con Lambda:
List costBeforeTax = Arrays.asList(100, 200, 300, 400, 500);
costBeforeTax.stream().map((cost) -> cost + .12*cost).forEach(System.out::println);
```

### Enlaces

- [Introducción a Expresiones Lambda](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/expresiones-lambda-api-stream-java-2633852-esa.html)
- [Tutorial de Oracle sobre las expresiones lambda (en inglés)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)
- [10 Example of Lambda Expressions and Streams in Java 8](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/10-example-of-lambda-expressions-in-java8.html)

Comment: Su respuesta es genial. Ojalá pudiera darle más de 1 upvote.